English meaning of Dwadash stotra - preenayamo vasudevam by Shri Madhavacharya
Can anyone kindly share the meaning of the preenayamo vasudevam Dwadash stotra composed by Shri Madhavacharya. I am trying to do it manually with online sources but now sure if its correct:
This is the link to the Stotra.
Here is my not so correct translation:
Verse 1:

    Vandita shesha vandyoru vrundaarakam: Adorned with garlands offered by countless devotees.
    Chandana charchito daara peenaamsakam: Sandalwood-scented broad chest.
    Indira chanchala paangda neerajitam: Eyes that surpass the beauty of Indra's dance.
    Mandarodhari vruttodhbhuja bhoginam: Adorned with the Mandara garland and possessing wonderful arms.
    Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We love Vasudeva, the destroyer of the pride of the assembly of gods.

Verse 2:

    Srushti samhara leelavila saatatam: Always engaged in the playful acts of creation and destruction.
    Pushta shadgunya sad-vigrahollasinam: Possessing a six-armed, auspicious form that is full of strength and virtues.
    Dushta nih shesha samhara kar modhyatam: The middle one among those who destroy the wicked at the end of time.
    Hrushta pushtathi shishta praja samshrayam: The refuge of the well-behaved people who are happy and prosperous.
    Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We love Vasudeva, the destroyer of the pride of the assembly of gods.

Verse 3:

    Unnata prarthitha shesha samsadhakam: The one who fulfills the desires of the exalted ones.
    Sannata lowkika nandada sreepadam: The auspicious abode of eternal bliss in the non-material world.
    Bhinna karmashaya prani samprerakam: The one who inspires creatures with different karmas.
    Tanna kim neti vidvatsu meemaamsitam: The subject of debate among scholars: "Is he God or not?"
    Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We love Vasudeva, the destroyer of the pride of the assembly of gods.

Verse 4:

    Vipra mukhyai sada vedava donmukhai: Always facing towards the Vedas for the sake of the Brahmins.
    Supratha paikshiti shaikshvarai-schachitam: Adorned with the sacred thread and the marks of a learned scholar.
    Apra tharkaryorusam vidgunam nirmalam: Spotless and full of knowledge that cannot be surpassed by any logic.
    Sapraka shajara nandaro pamparam: Decorated with a garland of Tulsi leaves and the Mandara flower.
    Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We love Vasudeva, the destroyer of the pride of the assembly of gods.

Verse 5:

    Attyayo yesya kenapi na kwapihi: There is no one who is superior to Him in any way.
    Pratyayo yadgune shuthamaa nam parah: We place our faith in His pure qualities.
    Satya sadkalpa yekovaren yovashi: He is the only one who is true, has good intentions, and is the one who fulfills all desires.
    Matya noonai sada vedava doditah: He is the one who is praised in the Vedas by the great sages.
    Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We love Vasudeva, the destroyer of the pride of the assembly of gods.

Verse 6:

    Pashyatam dukha santana nirmoolanam: He is the destroyer of the lineage of sorrow for those who see Him.
    Drushyatam drushyata Mityaje-sharshitam: He is the one who destroys the fear of death for those who see Him.
    Nashyatam dooragam sarvada-pyathmagam: He is the one who is always far away from destruction and the source of all souls.
    Vashyatam svecchaya sajjane-shwagatam: He is the one who is easily controlled by the devotees who are pure-hearted.
    Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We love Vasudeva, the destroyer of the pride of the assembly of gods.


can someone provide the correct explanation for all the verses ?

The Dwadasha Stotra, composed by the great Vedanta philosopher and Dvaita Vedanta proponent Shri Madhvacharya, is a collection of twelve hymns dedicated to Lord Vishnu, specifically in his form as Vasudeva. Here's an interpretation of the verses you provided, refined for clarity and fidelity to the original text's meaning:
Verse 1:
Vandita shesha vandyoru vrundaarakam: Adorned with garlands offered by countless devotees.
Chandana charchito daara peenaamsakam: Sandalwood-scented broad chest.
Indira chanchala paangda neerajitam: Eyes that surpass the beauty of Indra's dance.
Mandarodhari vruttodhbhuja bhoginam: Adorned with the Mandara garland and possessing wonderful arms.
Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We revere Vasudeva, the ornament of the assembly of gods.

Meaning:
We worship Vasudeva, who is adorned with garlands offered by the gods and devotees, whose chest is smeared with sandalwood, whose eyes surpass the beauty of Indra's dance, and who is decorated with the Mandara garland, possessing powerful arms. He is the delight of the divine assembly.
Verse 2:
Srushti samhara leelavila saatatam: Always engaged in the playful acts of creation and destruction.
Pushta shadgunya sad-vigrahollasinam: Possessing a form that is full of auspicious qualities and virtues.
Dushta nih shesha samhara kar modhyatam: The destroyer of the wicked.
Hrushta pushtathi shishta praja samshrayam: The refuge of the righteous and prosperous devotees.
Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We revere Vasudeva, the ornament of the assembly of gods.

Meaning:
We revere Vasudeva, who playfully engages in the acts of creation and destruction, whose form is full of auspicious virtues, who destroys the wicked, and who is the refuge of the righteous and prosperous devotees.
Verse 3:
Unnata prarthitha shesha samsadhakam: The one who fulfills the desires of the exalted ones.
Sannata lowkika nandada sreepadam: The auspicious abode of eternal bliss in the non-material world.
Bhinna karmashaya prani samprerakam: The one who inspires creatures with different karmas.
Tanna kim neti vidvatsu meemaamsitam: The subject of debate among scholars: "Is he God or not?"
Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We revere Vasudeva, the ornament of the assembly of gods.

Meaning:
We revere Vasudeva, who fulfills the desires of the exalted, who is the source of eternal bliss, who inspires beings according to their karmas, and who is debated among scholars as to whether He is truly the Supreme God.
Verse 4:
Vipra mukhyai sada vedava donmukhai: Always facing towards the Vedas for the sake of the Brahmins.
Supratha paikshiti shaikshvarai-schachitam: Adorned with the sacred thread and the marks of a learned scholar.
Apra tharkaryorusam vidgunam nirmalam: Spotless and full of knowledge that cannot be surpassed by any logic.
Saprakasha jara nandaro pamparam: Decorated with a garland of Tulsi leaves and the Mandara flower.
Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We revere Vasudeva, the ornament of the assembly of gods.

Meaning:
We revere Vasudeva, who is always attentive to the Vedas, who is adorned with the sacred thread and the marks of a scholar, who is spotless and whose knowledge is beyond logical debate, and who is adorned with a garland of Tulsi leaves and Mandara flowers.
Verse 5:
Attyayo yesya kenapi na kwapihi: There is no one who is superior to Him in any way.
Pratyayo yadgune shuthamaa nam parah: We place our faith in His pure qualities.
Satya sadkalpa yekovaren yovashi: He is the only one who is true, has good intentions, and fulfills all desires.
Matya noonai sada vedava doditah: He is the one who is praised in the Vedas by the great sages.
Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We revere Vasudeva, the ornament of the assembly of gods.

Meaning:
We revere Vasudeva, who has no superior, in whose pure qualities we place our faith, who alone is true and fulfills all good intentions, and who is praised in the Vedas by the great sages.
Verse 6:
Pashyatam dukha santana nirmoolanam: He is the destroyer of the lineage of sorrow for those who see Him.
Drushyatam drushyata Mityaje-sharshitam: He is the one who destroys the fear of death for those who see Him.
Nashyatam dooragam sarvada-pyathmagam: He is the one who is always far away from destruction and the source of all souls.
Vashyatam svecchaya sajjane-shwagatam: He is the one who is easily controlled by the devotees who are pure-hearted.
Preenayamo vasudevam devatha mandala khanda mandanam: We revere Vasudeva, the ornament of the assembly of gods.

Meaning:
We revere Vasudeva, who destroys the lineage of sorrow for those who see Him, who destroys the fear of death, who is far from destruction and the source of all souls, and who is controlled by the pure-hearted devotees.
This interpretation aligns with the traditional understanding of the Dwadasha Stotra, emphasizing Lord Vishnu's attributes, qualities, and the devotion He inspires among His devotees.
PLease note this translation is literal and will not have the real essence as Guru madhvacharya would intent. Kiny excuse me if this is not correct.

thanks, if its possible for you could translate all the verses, it would be helpful.
